# Uncaught TypeError: props.setDetailsShown is not a function (useState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm passing down a state as props but when I try to use the `setState`, it will show this:

> Uncaught TypeError: props.setDetailsShown is not a function

I'm passing from here:

```
export function Topology() {
    const [ detailsShown, setDetailsShown ] = useState(false);
    
    return (
        <TopologyGraph detailsShown={setDetailsShown} />      
    );
}
```

To here:

```
export function TopologyGraph(props) {

// graph event callbacks
const onClickNode = id => {
  console.log(`Clicked node ${id}`);
  props.setDetailsShown(true)
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing to `TopologyGraph` component as `detailsShown` attribute so try to call as:

```
const onClickNode = id => {
  console.log(`Clicked node ${id}`);
  props.detailsShown(true)
};
```

Or rename your attribute to `setDetailsShown` as:

```
<TopologyGraph setDetailsShown={setDetailsShown} />
```

At the end it can be called as `props.setDetailsShown(true)` in your original `onClickNode` function. I personally prefer the second option to rename to start the attribute's name with `set` keyword.

Comment: Thanks! it was my lack of attention

Comment: @YanVictor No issues, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `props.detailsShown(true)` as the prop name is `detailsShown` whose **value** is `setDetailsShown`.